# Give value to a date object from another and change only one

Tags: php, date, object

I'm new to php and I'm still trying to understand object usage.

This is my script:

```
$Date1=date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '2017-01-01');
$Date2=$Date1;
$Date2->modify('last day of');
echo '</br>Date1='.$Date1->format('Y-m-d');//output: Date1=2017-01-31
echo '</br>Date2='.$Date2->format('Y-m-d');//output: Date2=2017-01-31
```

My goal is to have two different date objects:

the 1st from the string date;

the 2nd containing the last day of the month

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clone` to create identical copy of object

```
$Date1=date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '2017-01-01');
$Date2=clone  $Date1;
$Date2->modify('last day of');
echo '</br>Date1='.$Date1->format('Y-m-d');
echo '</br>Date2='.$Date2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
    `$Date2 = clone $Date1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$Date1 = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' '2017-01-01');
```

The method you are using creates a mutable object, but you're looking for an immutable one. The immutable one will *return* a new date object instead of changing the current one.

See [documentation](http://php.net/datetimeimmutable) for the DateTimeImmutable class.

Comment: Thanks for the useful hint, but I don't need an immutable date object: I only need two different dates

Comment: That's exactly what the immutable date object gives you: when you call `modify` on it, it returns the second date object for you, so you have two dates.

Comment: Yes, but (later in the code) I need to be free to modify the 1st object

Comment: Ah, I see. So later on you'll be changing `$Date1` and actually want it to update that object? In that case, `clone $Date1` will probably suit your needs better, but in general `DateTimeImmutable` is the most useful option.